# java decryption algorithm giving java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -59

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption

I have a decryption algorithm and it compiles successfully but I get an exception while running it.

I've tried changing the order of where the `(byte)` is and adding more in but I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working.

Below is the `Crypt.java` code:

```
public class Crypt implements Runnable {
    public Crypt(byte[] data, int length, byte[] key) throws IOException {
        byte v3, v5, v6;
        int len = length;

        if (len > 0) {
            do {
                --len;
                v3 = (byte) (key[0] + 1);
                key[0] = v3;
                v5 = (byte) (key[4] + key[8 + v3]);
                key[4] = v5;
                v6 = key[8 + v3];
                key[8 + v3] = key[8 + v5];
                key[8 + key[4]] = v6;

                data[length - len - 1] ^= key[8 + (byte) (key[8 + key[4]] + key[8 + key[0]])];

                Log.logInfo("Packet Data: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(data) + "");
            }
            while (len > 0);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
    }
}
```

And below is the code that I am using to get the `Crypt.java` to run.

```
byte key[] = {
    (byte) 0x2b, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xda, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0x24, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x6a, (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x1b, (byte) 0x2c,
    (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0x61, (byte) 0x3e, (byte) 0xaf, (byte) 0xec, (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0x60, (byte) 0x38, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x46, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x0c, (byte) 0x2b, (byte) 0xb9, (byte) 0x6e, (byte) 0x2e,
    (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x5d, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xe8, (byte) 0x64, (byte) 0xe3, (byte) 0x70, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0xdb, (byte) 0x93, (byte) 0xda, (byte) 0xcc, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x18, (byte) 0x22, (byte) 0x5e,
    (byte) 0xdf, (byte) 0x94, (byte) 0x5a, (byte) 0x4f, (byte) 0x25, (byte) 0xbe, (byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0xb5, (byte) 0x4b, (byte) 0xb4, (byte) 0x17, (byte) 0x8b, (byte) 0xf4, (byte) 0x57, (byte) 0x39, (byte) 0xb3,
    (byte) 0xfe, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0x63, (byte) 0x7d, (byte) 0x1c, (byte) 0x9f, (byte) 0x7a, (byte) 0xca, (byte) 0x3a, (byte) 0x1e, (byte) 0x65, (byte) 0xa7, (byte) 0x68, (byte) 0xd1, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0x78,
    (byte) 0x67, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0xb2, (byte) 0x8d, (byte) 0xd9, (byte) 0x8e, (byte) 0x9e, (byte) 0x9c, (byte) 0xc9, (byte) 0xe9, (byte) 0x9b, (byte) 0xb6, (byte) 0xba, (byte) 0x75, (byte) 0x20,
    (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0xd3, (byte) 0x3f, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x6d, (byte) 0x41, (byte) 0x62, (byte) 0x2a, (byte) 0xc6, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0xc5, (byte) 0x5f, (byte) 0x7b, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0xc4,
    (byte) 0xf6, (byte) 0x3b, (byte) 0xef, (byte) 0x97, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0x92, (byte) 0x87, (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0xf7, (byte) 0x52, (byte) 0x7f, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0xdc, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0xd0,
    (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0x99, (byte) 0x9d, (byte) 0xe0, (byte) 0x0e, (byte) 0x29, (byte) 0x6c, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0xd5, (byte) 0xe7, (byte) 0xee, (byte) 0xfa, (byte) 0x59, (byte) 0xa9, (byte) 0x27,
    (byte) 0x26, (byte) 0xcd, (byte) 0xdd, (byte) 0xae, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x47, (byte) 0xe5, (byte) 0xf0, (byte) 0x37, (byte) 0x5b, (byte) 0x13, (byte) 0x4a, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0x4e,
    (byte) 0x72, (byte) 0xa6, (byte) 0x79, (byte) 0xd4, (byte) 0xa4, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0x36, (byte) 0xe6, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0xd7, (byte) 0x28, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0xf9, (byte) 0x2d, (byte) 0xbc, (byte) 0x12,
    (byte) 0xed, (byte) 0xbf, (byte) 0xad, (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0xce, (byte) 0x84, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x7c, (byte) 0xfb, (byte) 0x53, (byte) 0xe2, (byte) 0xea, (byte) 0x0d, (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0x1f, (byte) 0x54,
    (byte) 0xaa, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x23, (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x4c, (byte) 0x8c, (byte) 0x3d, (byte) 0xbd, (byte) 0xa1, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xb7, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x42, (byte) 0x4d, (byte) 0xa5,
    (byte) 0x8f, (byte) 0x3c, (byte) 0x85, (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0x77, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x0a, (byte) 0x1a, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xc0, (byte) 0xb1, (byte) 0xeb, (byte) 0x5c, (byte) 0x71,
    (byte) 0xd8, (byte) 0xc2, (byte) 0x8a, (byte) 0x0f, (byte) 0x76, (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0xa0, (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0xf5, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0x69, (byte) 0xe1, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0xd2,
    (byte) 0xab, (byte) 0xc1, (byte) 0x9a, (byte) 0x51, (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0xb8, (byte) 0xa3, (byte) 0xd6, (byte) 0xcb, (byte) 0xe4, (byte) 0xcf, (byte) 0x2f, (byte) 0xf8, (byte) 0xbb,
    (byte) 0x16, (byte) 0x66, (byte) 0xb0, (byte) 0x49, (byte) 0xac, (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0xf1, (byte) 0x7e
};

new Thread(new Crypt(request, size, key)).start();
```

The variable `request` from the above code is byte.
The `size` variable is basically the length of the `request` variable.

I've spent countless hours working on this and I just have no clue about why it isn't working.

When the program runs I get the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -59
        at com.webraid.cocproxy.utils.Crypt.<init>(Crypt.java:33)
        at com.webraid.cocproxy.network.Client.run(Client.java:97)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

*"Packet data"* is printed out twice. Once before it is put through the `Crypt.java` file and then after as you can see in the code. The two results are very similar but only the first 2 values are changed.

In this case the **02** became **1A**.

EDIT:

Line 33 in `Crypt.java` is: `key[8 + v3] = key[8 + v5];`

And line 97 in the `Client.java` code is: `new Thread(new Crypt(request, size, key)).start();`

Adding output here:

```
 Packet Data: 023E12AFF65CAFE52FB389F8FFFB7EAFEA81E672159DD38CDCF26A44895871B727CEB02976E85F658472C66ADA79CB49B47340523E643F0DFB3D4E5C7B5B1239296E26313
 5A2BB400FDD9E935D4255FE4CF0FF4BD87ED6359896A82B50753E3A3A9A998217640E1247C3AF153AFCF2E6351DE55AEFFAD000AF98549A28DA8823928A4496582476E29ADEB942634C68C
 291A711CA140BE4403F76F6F827E22204755396D0F546702ED20C3595A37D2A8B529963BD505FF34521792510DD27225FC1758B17DA6936F2ECCBAD7E55425B3F5328AA503DF610484B018
 8289D36ED777B6641A4A765743EAC6E0D8E8A28510D3CAAF18B2D

 Packet Data: 1A3E12AFF65CAFE52FB389F8FFFB7EAFEA81E672159DD38CDCF26A44895871B727CEB02976E85F658472C66ADA79CB49B47340523E643F0DFB3D4E5C7B5B1239296E26313
 5A2BB400FDD9E935D4255FE4CF0FF4BD87ED6359896A82B50753E3A3A9A998217640E1247C3AF153AFCF2E6351DE55AEFFAD000AF98549A28DA8823928A4496582476E29ADEB942634C68C
 291A711CA140BE4403F76F6F827E22204755396D0F546702ED20C3595A37D2A8B529963BD505FF34521792510DD27225FC1758B17DA6936F2ECCBAD7E55425B3F5328AA503DF610484B018
 8289D36ED777B6641A4A765743EAC6E0D8E8A28510D3CAAF18B2D
```

Comment: I think the issue is on data[length - len - 1], I should try to print the value of (length - len - 1) on each loop...

Comment: Added an edit which shows which the line numbers

Comment: it printed 0 and then gave the same error @vathek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on:

```
v5 = (byte) (key[4] + key[8 + v3]);
v6 = key[8 + v3];
key[8 + v3] = key[8 + v5];
key[8 + key[4]] = v6; 

....key[8 + (byte)(key[8 + key[4]] + key[8 + key[0]])]
```

With your data on second loop key[8 + v3] means k[-59].
The Java byte are signed, so you can have negative values on bytes.
Also, you are not sure that bytes on your key are between 0 and key.lenght().

You should be review the crypt alghorithm to ensure stay in boundary of 'key' array.

A possibile solution is to use a method that 'normalize' input to stay on range 0-key.lenght:

ex.

```
private int normalizeIndex(byte[] key, int index){
        return Math.abs(index)%(key.length-1);
    }
```

Then use it when retrieve array cells:

```
...
 v6 = key[normalizeIndex(key,8 + v3)];
 key[ normalizeIndex(key,(8 + v3))] = key[ normalizeIndex(key,(8 + v5))];
 key[normalizeIndex(key,8 + key[4])] = v6;

 data[length - len - 1] ^= key[normalizeIndex(key,8+(int)(key[ normalizeIndex(key,8 + key[4])]) + key[ normalizeIndex(key,8 + key[0])])];
...
```

Hope helped you!

Comment: Thanks but i'm not sure how to fix it - any ideas?

Comment: I edited the answer with a working solution. I don't know if it fit your specifications, but is the best I can do with information that I have!